# Error when using Json Library: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, g++, jsoncpp

I try to read a file as json in C++.

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream template_file("data.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    Json::Value template_data;
    template_file >> template_data;
    std::cout << template_data;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following error when the Json Library is included.

```
$ g++ test_json.cpp -std=c++11 -v
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test_json.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=11.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 650.9 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Projects/src/cpp -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -o /var/folders/tw/sd7wj26s5078tvqmd5z58m5r0000gn/T/test_json-c87926.o -x c++ test_json.cpp
clang -cc1 version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9) default target x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 11.0.0 11.3 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/tw/sd7wj26s5078tvqmd5z58m5r0000gn/T/test_json-c87926.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-c87926.o
  "Json::Value::~Value()", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-c87926.o
  "Json::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-c87926.o
  "Json::operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-c87926.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The operating system is macOS Big Sur 11.1. The versions of Xcode are:

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 12.5
Build version 12E262
$ xcode-select -version
xcode-select version 2384.
```

The Json Library seems to exist:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib
```

How could the error be solved?

**EDIT**

I tried to link the library as suggested in comment, but still no success:

```
$ g++ test_json.cpp -std=c++11 -l/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib/libjsoncpp.dylib
ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib/libjsoncpp.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
$ g++ test_json.cpp -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-9ed007.o
  "Json::Value::~Value()", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-9ed007.o
  "Json::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-9ed007.o
  "Json::operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-9ed007.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
$ g++ test_json.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-e8adec.o
  "Json::Value::~Value()", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-e8adec.o
  "Json::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-e8adec.o
  "Json::operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Json::Value&)", referenced from:
      _main in test_json-e8adec.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to link to the jsoncpp library

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried to link the library (c.f. edit in question), but still no success.. how can the library be linked?

Comment: If you're using the full path to the library just put the path with no prefix, for `-l` it would be `-ljsoncpp` in combination with `-L/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib`